# How curruent location latitude longitude periodically update

Tags: android

I am new to android. I want to send latitude longitude to web service which is periodically update at time interval of 15 minute. Even if my device is in spleep mode.Even if my application is not active. Even if phone is not moving for long period.Even if user is moving fast. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think i covered whole think what you needded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's what you need ;)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

this line in the code on that page sets the update rate.

```
    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

here's som more info on how it works

```
    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String, long, float, android.app.PendingIntent)
```

but keep in mind to stop the location updates when their not needed, it's heavy on the battery

Answer (score 1):

ok,

```
1.Lets start from the first, "periodically update at time interval of 15 minute"
->for this we already suggest you to use service and timer or alarm manager.

2. "Even if my device is in spleep mode".
-> For this you prevent to going your device in sleep mode for that you can use android's WAKE_LOCK. 

3. "Even if my application is not active".
-> I think for this, you can start a service at the device boot time, and it is countinuesly going to run..

4. "Even if phone is not moving for long period.Even if user is moving fast".
-> for this from service save your lat,long at every 15 minutes and also check whether
   location is updated or not if updated then just update your lat,long also, and then just
   send the lat, long for every 15 minutes.
```

Hope you will understand it,Thanks,

Comment: hi,may i know how to update the mapview of current activity with latest locations which are retrieved by the "service" as per your above answer.